# Build a docker image on Gitlab CI/CD with alpine

Tags: docker, continuous-integration, gitlab, wget, docker-volume

I would like to build docker-image on Gitlab CI/CD with alpine. This docker has to download a website (only index.html) as a file with a date every 1 hour. 
All dates/ files should be saved in the docker volume.

How to start with this? I am new in docker.

Answer (score 2):

- First you need to run a docker container using any image you want (alpine in your case).
- Then set everything in it that you want to run (like download website)
- Then create a docker image and host it on gitlab docker registry
- Then you simply have to code `.gitlab-ci.yaml` file.  After pushing that to your repository
- Then you need to schedule your pipeline as mentioned here
  https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/pipelines/schedules.html

Comment: Steps 1-3 should _always_ be in a `Dockerfile`; once you have your CI system set up, it can rebuild the image if there is any change.

Comment: Yes. It depends on you. that whether you want to have use the docker image or the Dockerfile. If you'll use the docker image, then pipeline will complete quickly because it don't have to build the container every time.